# How to redirect output from <None> type object to text file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am struck in one problem.I am trying to redirect the output stream to text file but the problem that is coming is the object through which i am redirecting is of type **None**. After redirecting to file, the only output i am able to see is **None**.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def stdout_redirected(new_stdout):
   save_stdout = sys.stdout
   sys.stdout = new_stdout
   try:
       yield None
   finally:
       sys.stdout = save_stdout

    with open('output3.txt', "w") as f:
        with stdout_redirected(f):
            XYZ = hid.core.show_hids(target_vid=vendor, target_pid=product)
            print XYZ
```

How to redirect the output from none type object ?

Comment: If `XYZ` is `None`, you don't *have* an output stream. Something probably went wrong with `hid.core.show_hids`.

Comment: output stream is there but i am not able to redirect the stream in file.

Comment: What does "output stream is there" mean? Does `show_hids` *itself* write to standard output? If that's the case, its return value really is `None` and isn't useful; you have to check its documentation to see if there is a way to have it write to a different file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *redirect* the output from a None type object. Such objects don't have any output.

*Nothing* you can do in your code is going to make this line

```
XYZ = hid.core.show_hids(target_vid=des, target_pid=bes)
```

work the way you want it to. That is because your code is assigning the return value of the function to `XYZ` and `show_hids()` returns the value `None`. You may think that is not how it should work, but that is how it actually does work. If a function does `return None`, or (as in this case) lacks a `return` statement, then *`None` is what you are going to get back and you can't change that* without rewriting the function.

You can see output, so `show_hids()` is clearly sending that output to the console itself. If you want it to go somewhere else you have to get `show_hids()` to send the output where you want it.

You were advised in the comments to consult the documentation on this subject. Understand that small third-party libraries maintained by only one or two people are likely to have documentation that is less comprehensive than you would like. That in turn means it may take a little more work to consult. In this case, all you needed to do was go to the project page on GitHub and look at the [examples folder](https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb/blob/master/examples/show_hids.py), which contains sample code called `show_hids.py` and that contains this sample Python 2 call:

```
output = codecs.getwriter('mbcs')(sys.stdout)
hid.core.show_hids(output = output)
```

This makes it very clear that you are expected to pass an open file object as the parameter `output` to the function if you want the output to go somewhere other than `sys.stdout`.

But that may only get you so far. Some USB devices have Unicode characters in the device names, and when I run the the sample code under Python 2 it chokes on the name *Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000* because of the trademark sign. And fiddling with `codecs.getwriter()` won't change that because the problem isn't happening at the output stage.

I've posted it as an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb/issues/55) but if it were up to me I would flag it *Will not fix* because it is a pure Python 2 problem, and support for Python 2 ends this year.

So if you run into this problem I recommend that you switch to Python 3. Teaching yourself Python 2 is a dead end.

Then all you need to do is this:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\xxxxx\55561448.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    hid.core.show_hids(output=f)
```

When I suggested in the comment that you try reassigning `sys.stdout` as a last resort, this is what I meant:

```
default_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('help.txt', 'w')
hid.core.show_hids(target_vid=des, target_pid=bes)
sys.stdout = default_stdout
```

That temporarily monkeypatches `sys.stdout` so that `show_hids()` will do what you want. But there is no need to do that in this case because the `show_hids()` itself provides a means to send the output where you want.

Comment: So is there any workaround for this ? I am able to see output in run time but not able to redirect the output stream.

Comment: If you can see output then the function you are calling is sending it to the console. Your code is expecting to get it back in the return value of the function but the function isn't doing that. There  may be a way to pass a file to the function but only its documentation will tell you that.

Comment: I saw in the documentation but didn't get much clarification on this part.Is there any other way to redirect in file ?

Comment: There is *nothing* coming back from the function for you to redirect. You could try reassigning `says.stdout` to `f` before calling the function. Very much a last resort.

Comment: Its not helping .I tried but didn't get the desired result.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. Edit your question and add that.

Comment: I added the code .I am not sure it is what you expected . Please confirm .This one gives me output like this:  <open file 'help.txt', mode 'w' at 0x000000000396F8A0>.Please correct if its wrong ,I am struck here.

Comment: @ChiragDhingra I have extended the answer to include the documentation you could not find. Redirecting `stdout` using a context manager is a reasonable approach, but you clearly did not grasp how it was supposed to work. So I would back out that edit and restore your original code which at least makes clear what the misunderstanding was.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive detail over the issue.I really appreciate that .I tried another way & i am able to redirect the output in file .I had done in python 2.7 .Please see my edit.Its working fine in python 2.